# On a Debian 7.5 rc.local won't be run at boot

Tags: linux, debian, init.d, rc.local

I am struggling to figure out why rc.local won't be executed at boot time.
The file itself is executable, it is called from /etc/rc2.d
Also the file when from command line won't return any errors.
Any ideas what else to check to figure out why is not run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that `rc.local` executes properly when you run it manually, the two things that immediately come to mind are:

- Something is going wrong at boot time but works when you run it yourself. Perhaps you're trying to run a program that's not in the PATH at boot time.
- `/etc/rc.local` really isn't being run at boot.

In both cases, the first thing I'd do is put something like

```
/usr/bin/printenv > /var/tmp/rc.local-$(date +%T)
```

as the very first line of `rc.local` after the `#!/bin/sh` line. That'll print the environment variables to a timestamped file every it is run. (Don't write the file to `/tmp` because that's emptied at boot.) Run `/etc/rc.local` manually and take a quick look at the resulting file (it'll be named something like `/var/tmp/rc.local-21:14:35`). Then reboot your system.

You should have two files in `/var/tmp` (or wherever) that you can compare. If you only the first file, `/etc/rc.local` isn't really getting called. If you have two files, compare them. The later one will have a *very* sparse environment and PATH. Look through your `rc.local` script and see if there's anything you're trying to run that depends on some variable or some component of PATH that's not in the boot-time environment. If you find something, add the necessary initialization to `rc.local`.